# Query currently available accelerator table entries - possible?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

In C#, via platform invoke (or other method), is there a way to obtain/inspect a list of all accelerator table entries for the module that currently has focus? For example, if Chrome currently has the focus, I want to get a list of all applicable keyboard shortcut's available (ctrl+T, ctrl+N, ctrl+shift+N, etc).

Comment: Apps are welcome to (and Chrome almost certainly does) use a custom algorithm for accelerators rather than using the system-provided accelerator table object. So you'd have to have special case for each app to interrogate its accelerators in some app-specific way.

Comment: Chrome was just an example. For an application that does use system accelerator tables, is there a way?

Comment: If the app exposes its accelerators via UIAutomation, you can query for the [AcceleratorKeyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.acceleratorkeyproperty?view=netcore-3.1). But if it doesn't, then you're back to doing case-by-case analysis because the app isn't publishing its accelerators anywhere.

Comment: It is possible to get access to the accelerators that belong to any particular table but not, as far as I am aware, a way to get a list of tables. Even if you did get such a list there is no guarantee that it would be 'active' at the current time. Note it is possible to get a list of accelerator resources (via EnumResourceNames etc) but it is also possible to create accelerator tables at runtime. Accelerators are one resource with a simple memory format so, unlike say dialogs, it's not unreasonable to do this.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir For my needs, when SomeApp.exe has the focus, I need to be able to differentiate between a random <modifier>+<anykey> key press and a shortcut defined by SomeApp.exe. It is not important for me to know what that shortcut does or the context in which it is active. Rather that it is a shortcut defined by SomeApp.exe. 
You said 'It is possible to get access to the accelerators that belong to any particular table'. Assuming I have a reference to a particular table, can you elaborate what API functions and/or algorithm is used to access the accelerator entries in that table?

Comment: @RaymondChen I had not thought about that strategy which may be very applicable for what I am doing. Thanks for that suggestion!

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve? The answer to the question asked (if it exists) is not entirely useful. Any application can respond to any kind of keyboard input in any way it chooses. It need not use the system provided accelerator tables for this.

Comment: @IInspectable For my needs, when SomeApp.exe has the focus, I need to be able to differentiate between a random <modifier>+<anykey> key press and a shortcut defined by SomeApp.exe. It is not important for me to know what that shortcut does or the context in which it is active. Rather that it is a shortcut defined by SomeApp.exe. I realize that whatever is developed for this will likely rely on multiple strategies and never be 100%. I am just asking about how accelerator tables might be used to provide one source of shortcut definitions if available by a given app. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you have an HACCEL handle the CopyAcceleratorTable function allows you to get the data that defines the actual keys (and generated command messages). But as Raymond Chen says, this is of limited use when trying to deal with random apps.

Comment: But what's the difference between "Shift+X is a shortcut for Mark Message Read" and "Shift+X is a shortcut for entering a capital X"? They are both keypresses that cause the app to do *something*. Accelerators are exposed to UI Automation so that accessibility tools can say things like "Press Shift+X to mark message read" so that users with visual impairments know what other options are available.